# Get element of list recursively

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I'm working on a project and I've faced the following problem.

I have a `Client` object which contains an `ArrayList<Client>` linked attribute.
A `Client` can be link to other `Client`. The linked `Client` of `Client` are stored in this list ( Which form a sort of a graph).

I would like to make a method which can return all client thanks to a recursive call on the linked attribute.

This is my code:

```
public class Client implements Serializable{        

    String name;
    String ipAddress;
    ArrayList<Client> linked;       

    //Constructor
    public Client(String name, String ipAddress)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.ipAddress=ipAddress;
        linked=new ArrayList<Client>();
    }

    public void addInList(Client c)
    {
        linked.add(c);
    }
}
```

My recursiv method is:

```
public ArrayList<Client> getAllClient(ArrayList<Client> list)
{        
    for(Client c : linked)
    {
        if(!linked.contains(c))
        {
            linked.add(c);
            getAllClient(list);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

I know it is a basic problem but I can not find a solution. What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: What is the problem ? Something does not work ?

Comment: should it not be c.getAllClient(list) inside the getAllClient method?

Comment: When I test my method, it return an empty list. And yes I've forgot to add c.getAllClient(list) thank !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parameter as `outputList` to be able to track the clients already added to the list within the recursion. It will add all the original clients and all the clients linked to the original list and so on.

```
public ArrayList<Client> getAllClients(List<Client> outputList, List<Client> list) {
    for (Client client : list) {
        if (!outputList.contains(client)) {
            getAllClients(outputList, client.getLinked());
            outputList.add(client);
        }
    }
    return outputList;
}
```

Comment: It's best to post a little description along with your code, instead of only code.

Comment: @MCEmperor Was coming :) You are too quick for me